# Why is "uname gcc" not working in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

I know that `uname -a` shows the full machine name and details, etc. But I did `uname gcc` to see what the version of gcc I am running, and it returned `Linux` - **What does that mean?**

```
Ubuntu86: $ uname gcc
Linux
```

This is the machine I am on (I know it is old):

```
Ubuntu86: $ uname -a
Linux ubuntu86 2.6.8.1-3-386 #1 Tue Oct 12 12:41:57 BST 2004 i686 GNU/Linux
```

How can I check the version of gcc running on this machine?

I installed it by typing:

```
Ubuntu86: $ sudo apt-get install gcc
```

So I know it has installed a version of gcc, but no idea what version.

Comment: **Generally speaking:** You shouldn't be passing random parameters to programs. It's harmless in the case of `uname`, but it can easily cause programs to perform operations you really don't want to do. Check the man page of the command in question to see what parameters it accepts and what they mean. (Many also do something reasonably safe when invoked with simply the name of the binary with no parameters.)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKjörling, I have been working a lot in SCO, so I forgot about all this with the man pages and the `-v` option. I will keep that in mind for the future :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And for the first question: `uname`, when passed no option, is equivalent to `uname -s` thus displays `Linux` on your system.

The `gcc` argument passed is not an option (doesn't start with an hyphen) so is simply ignored by the command.

Comment: So you saying, whatever follows `uname` needs to start with a hyphen, in order for it to work properly?

Comment: Try `uname --help` or `man uname` for list of available options.

Comment: It already works properly. This command only expect options and ignore anything else. This is unusual. Many commands report unexpected parameters with a warning or an error.

Answer (score 4):

`uname` shows the name of the OS you're working on - it just ignored the argument and did its usual work. It does not display versions of installed software.

Most commands - including `gcc` support `--version` argument, so `gcc --version` displays your current GCC version.

Comment: Ok, that is a bit simpler than `gcc -v`, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the second question the answer is: `gcc -v`
On the last line of the print out you can find the version of `gcc` installed on your system.

Comment: Great, thanks. It is showing: `gcc version 3.3.4 (Debian 1:3.3.4-9ubuntu5)` - why Debian? Or is that just the version?

Comment: Welcome! Because Ubuntu is actually a Debian based distro.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian-based systems, including Ubuntu, you can find out the installation status as well as the possibly installed version of a package (if you know the package name) using `dpkg -l` (that's ell, not I or one). Doing so generally does not require root access, as it is a read-only operation.

To find out which package owns a specific file, use `dpkg -S`. Again, this does not require root access.

Putting the two together, you get something like:

```
$ dpkg -S $(which gcc)
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc
$ dpkg -l gcc
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name              Version       Architecture  Description
+++-=================-=============-=============-=======================================
ii  gcc               4:4.7.2-1     amd64         GNU C compiler
$
```

which tells me that on my particular system, package version `4:4.7.2-1` of the `gcc` package for the `amd64` architecture is fully installed and configured (`ii` status).

If you want a single command, it would be `dpkg -l $(dpkg -S $(which gcc) | awk -F: '{print $1}')` which will show the same output as the `dpkg -l gcc` command example above. Here I use awk to split the data on `:` and return the first portion of the output.

Note that the package version does not necessarily exactly reflect the version that the program itself reports. In my case, `gcc --version` says it is `gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2` which for all practical purposes is "close enough", but it may make a difference if you are trying to figure out of a behavior you are seeing is a bug or not.

Even more generally, **you shouldn't be passing random parameters to programs** and expecting things to work (for some definition of "work"). In the specific case of `uname`, it's harmless, but it can easily cause programs to perform operations you really don't want to do; some even potentially dangerous. Check the man page of the command in question to see what parameters it accepts and what they mean. (Many also do something reasonably safe when invoked with simply the name of the binary with no parameters. Lots of console applications will display version and copyright information when launched with no parameters, though there are many that do things differently.)